# Sort a PowerShell OrderedDictionary with custom objects

Tags: powershell, ordereddictionary

I have created an OrderedDictionary filled with custom objects. Each object has two properties:

```
$myCustomObject.name = "foo"
$myCustomObject.date = <datetime here>
$orderedDictionary.add(<value here>,$MyObject)
```

I need to sort all the $myCustomObject items by date. How do I do that?

Please note I can't add the items into the ordered dictionary in sorted order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this line of code:

```
$ordered = $myCustomObject | sort dateProperty
```

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7) for sort object adjusted as you need.

Comment: I have a set of $MyCustomObject items in the Ordered Dictionary object $orderedDictionary. Will this method work for that?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my sample code

```
PS C:\> $orderedDictionary = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

1..5 | % {

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

    $myCustomObject = "" | select name, date

    $myCustomObject.name = "foo$_"
    $myCustomObject.date = (Get-Date)

    $orderedDictionary.Add($_,$myCustomObject)

}
```

**Direct output:**

```
PS C:\> $orderedDictionary

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                 
1                              @{name=foo1; date=4/9/2020 10:01:32 AM}                                                                                                               
2                              @{name=foo2; date=4/9/2020 10:01:34 AM}                                                                                                               
3                              @{name=foo3; date=4/9/2020 10:01:36 AM}                                                                                                               
4                              @{name=foo4; date=4/9/2020 10:01:38 AM}                                                                                                               
5                              @{name=foo5; date=4/9/2020 10:01:40 AM}
```

**Sorted Output (Descending):**

```
PS C:\> $orderedDictionary.Values | sort date -Descending

name date                
---- ----                
foo5 4/9/2020 10:01:40 AM
foo4 4/9/2020 10:01:38 AM
foo3 4/9/2020 10:01:36 AM
foo2 4/9/2020 10:01:34 AM
foo1 4/9/2020 10:01:32 AM
```

Hope this helps.